# How to handle infinite scrolling using Playwright-Test?

Tags: playwright

I am writing a code using playwright test and its working fine in debug mode but normally its not able to find the element because not able to scroll down the page., I have tried using scrollintoview and mouse.move funtion as well.

Comment: If the element exists on the DOM, it automatically scrolls into view before performing an action on the element. Try using the different selector.

Comment: The element is not visible on the dom it gets loaded after scrolling down only.

Comment: This is most likely *infinite scrolling*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77084272

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Even using [locator.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-scroll-into-view-if-needed) won't help as element is not in the dom yet and we don't know any fixed location to look for it. The only way we can reach to it by doing scrolling.

> What you are facing most likely is *infinite scrolling* same like
> youtube where videos are keep getting loaded as you scroll more and
> more so till an element is not visible in the dom , playwright won't
> be able to act on it.

#### So ,how to handle infinite scrolling using Playwright?

**Solution**: Basically we need to keep on scrolling down in the page till the desired element becomes visible in the dom else either it times out or we reach the bottom of the page.

```
async scrollUntilElementIsVisible(page, locator) {
        while (!(await locator.isVisible())) {
            await page.mouse.wheel(0, 600);
        }
    }
```

References: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4302
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/11547
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5052

Comment: Please let me know if it helped or even if didn't work in your scenario so that I help you further and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [locator.focus()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-focus) instead which will do the scrolling for you.

```
await locator.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, this may work well:

```
await page.keyboard.press('End');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform the click operation on that element, then page.click() function internally scroll into view to the target element.

Reference:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click

**page.click(selector[, options])**

This method clicks an element matching selector by performing the following steps:

1. Find an element matching selector. If there is none, wait until a matching element is attached to the DOM.
2. Wait for actionability checks on the matched element, unless force option is set. If the element is detached during the checks, the whole action is retried.
3. **Scroll the element into view if needed.**
4. Use page.mouse to click in the center of the element, or the specified position.
5. Wait for initiated navigations to either succeed or fail, unless noWaitAfter option is set.

Comment: Element is not visible in the dom unless you scroll the page then the elements get loaded , so page.click(selector,[,options] is not working

Comment: I'd consider pressing the `END` button, wait for an element to be displayed, and then clicking on it..